# Updating prop on a specific component based on API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API which with an object and encapsulates errors related with each inputField within it, for example:

```
{
"success": false,
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"errors": {
    "firstname": [
        "Invalid firstname", 
        "Firstname must be at least 2 characters long"
    ], 
    "companyname": ["company name is a required field"]
   }
}
```

based on the errors, I need to display the error right below the input element, for which the code looks like this:

```
    class RegistrationComponent extends  Component {

      onSubmit = (formProps) => {

         this.props.signup(formProps, () => {
           this.props.history.push('/signup/complete');
         });
      };

    render() {
        const {handleSubmit} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <form
                  className='form-signup'
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}
                >
              <Field name='companyname' type='text' component={inputField} className='form-control' validate={validation.required} />
              <Field name='firstname' type='text' component={inputField} className='form-control' validate={validation.required} />
<Translate
                    content='button.register'
                    className='btn btn-primary btn-form'
                    type='submit'
                    component='button'
                  />
                </form>
            </div>
      );}}
```

The inputField:

```
export const inputField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  className,
  id,
  placeholder,
  meta: { error, touched },
  disabled
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {label ? (
        <label>
          <strong>{label}</strong>
        </label>
      ) : null}
      <Translate
        {...input}
        type={type}
        color={"white"}
        className={className}
        id={id}
        disabled={disabled}
        component="input"
        attributes={{ placeholder: placeholder }}
      />
      <InputFieldError
        touched={touched}
        error={<Translate content={error} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and finally;

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class InputFieldError extends Component {
  render() {
    return <font color="red">{this.props.touched && this.props.error}</font>;
  }
}

export default InputFieldError;
```

If I validate simply with `validate={validation.required}` the error property is attached to the correct input field and I can render the error div using InputFieldError right below it.

I am mapping all the errors back from the API response on to props like this:

```
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return { errorMessage: state.errors, countries: state.countries };
    }
```

which means I can print every error that I encounter at any place like this:

```
{this.props.errorMessage
                    ? displayServerErrors(this.props.errorMessage)
                    : null}
```

rendering all at same place by simply going through each property on errorMessage is easy.

Now when I try to assign the errors back from the API (`"errors": {"firstname": []}` is linked with `Field name="firstname"` and so on...), I cannot find a way to attach the error in "firstname" property to the correct InputFieldError component in `Field name="firstname"`

I hope the question is clear enough, to summarise it I am trying to render error I got from API to their respective input element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass errors.firstname to field inner component like this

```
<Field name='companyname' type='text' component={<inputField apiErrors={this.props.errorMessage.errors.firstname || null} {...props}/>} className='form-control' validate={validation.required} />
```

and then your inputField will be:

```
export const inputField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  className,
  id,
  placeholder,
  meta: { error, touched },
  apiErrors,
  disabled
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {label ? (
        <label>
          <strong>{label}</strong>
        </label>
      ) : null}
      <Translate
        {...input}
        type={type}
        color={"white"}
        className={className}
        id={id}
        disabled={disabled}
        component="input"
        attributes={{ placeholder: placeholder }}
      />
      <InputFieldError
        touched={touched}
        error={apiErrors ? apiErrors : <Translate content={error} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and:

```
class InputFieldError extends Component {
  render() {
    const errors = this.props.error
    let errorContent;
    if (Array.isArray(errors)) {
      errorContent = '<ul>'
      errors.map(error, idx => errorContent+= <li key={idx}><Translate content={error}/></li>)
      errorContent += '</ul>'
    } else {
      errorContent = errors
    }
    return <font color="red">{this.props.touched && errorContent}</font>;
  }
}
```

You can also add the main error at the top of your form

```
class RegistrationComponent extends  Component {

  onSubmit = (formProps) => {

     this.props.signup(formProps, () => {
       this.props.history.push('/signup/complete');
     });
  };

render() {
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.errorMessage.message && 
             <Alert>
               <Translate content={this.props.errorMessage.message}/>
             </Alert>
            }
            <form
              className='form-signup'
              onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}
            >
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this would more or less work yes, however this would mean adding extra check and value to each component, ``apiErrors={(this.props.errorMessage&& this.props.errorMessage.company_name) || null }`` since this project is a temporary gig for me I wanted to avoid modifying each and every file.

Comment: In your mapsStateToProps function, you can initialise default empty errorMessage props if there is noting in redux store. Or you can reset errors state to default value in store reducer.